# Symfony 2 Override Entity and add extra properties

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I have entity A and entity B which extend entity A.

Entity A - in vendor bundle.
Entity B - in /src bundle.

I search a lot of time and only solution works for me. It's using `ClassMetadataListener` on Doctrine Event `loadClassMetadata`.

But extending on entity B not works. I need add all properties form entity A to entity B.

I can't understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot simply extend a class like normally when using Doctrine2.

Check the documentation on [chapter **6. Inheritance Mapping**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) on how to implement inheritance on your entity classes.

You are probably interested [in chapter **6.1. Mapped Superclasses**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses).

> A mapped superclass is an abstract or concrete class that provides persistent entity state and mapping information for its subclasses, but which is not itself an entity. Typically, the purpose of such a mapped superclass is to define state and mapping information that is common to multiple entity classes.

For this to work you have to use the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation to your entity base class.

Comment: with MappedSuperclass you can.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrauze Isn't that exactly what is explained in the documentation that I am referring to in my answer. I will add a quote from there to my answer...

Comment: yes you added part about MappedSuperclass after my post and the post of mmoreram. Earlier it wasn't obvious.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to achieve that without a MappedSuperclass ? In case of an extension of a defined entity in another module without a new table creation ... just to add one property / field in an existing table e.g.

Comment: @ceadreak Yes, this is called [single table inheritance handled in chapter 6.2](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance). You will get an additional so called discriminator column to distinguish the different classes that will be stored in the same table.

Comment: @Wilt It's exactly that I don't want (add a discriminator column). Example : Imagine a "core" module containing a User entity. In a new module (depending of this core module), I want to extends the base User entity with a new property (and a new field in users table). I don't want to update the base User entity to set it as MappedSuperclass or add a discriminator column. So, I think it's not possible without custom components

Comment: Do you want those new properties also to be added to existing users? Or will it be only for new users?

Comment: @Wilt Yes I want new properties for both existing users and new users. Is there a different if new properties applied only for new users ?

Comment: Not sure if it applies to all your needs, but you could consider to do like this, make an `ExtendedUser` entity where you add all new properties and make a one to one unidirectional relationship to `User`. You could even make the user to the identifier column. Now make proxy methods to all your `User` entity properties. Your new `ExtendedUser` will behave like your user with the new properties and you don't need to make any changes to the `User` entity or your user table.

Answer (score 1):

Add @MappedSuperclass annotation in top of A. That would be enough :)